# How to convert a numpy array of tensors to a tensor?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have a numpy array list something like the follows:

```
a=np.array([tf.convert_to_tensor(1),tf.convert_to_tensor(2)])
```

I want to convert this list into a tensor.
My real list is not like the constant example but some complex tensor, so does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume all of the tensors have the same shape. Then you can just call [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack):

```py
>>> print(tf.stack([tf.convert_to_tensor(1), tf.convert_to_tensor(2)]))
Tensor("stack:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

Note that it accepts the list, not numpy array.